# Pan sharpening with surface reflectance data

Tags: r, landsat, landsat-8, pansharpening

The surface reflectance data for landsat 8 is only available for bands 1-7 (via EPSA bulk download). I want to pan sharpen surface reflectance data. But I don't have a surface reflectance band 8 (pan band).

Do you think I can use for pan sharpening the surface reflectance data (band 1-7) with the raw DN pan band, as I don't have a surfcace reflectance panchromatic band?

Comment: I tried this. it doesn't work because the level 1 top of atmosphere panchromatic band has a different spectral distribution than the surface reflectance products from usgs for the landsat bands 1-7. I think only the smoothing filter intensity modulation method would work, but it is very sensitive to band misregistration errors typically found in landsat data.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an 16-bit panchromatic band to correct the floating point radiance or reflectance band(s). Why don't just correct the panchromatic band to reflectance? The procedure is quite a bit more straightforward that it was with the previous sensors and the coefficients are standard across scenes. The USGS has provided [instructions](http://landsat.usgs.gov/Landsat8_Using_Product.php) that can be implemented using standard raster algebra. Here is a [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176351/landsat-8-reflectance-calibration) that gives the basic correction formula in a generic raster algebra format.