# Landsat 8 reflectance calibration

Tags: landsat-8, reflectance

I am calibrating my landsat data to reflectance with correction for sun angle. I just want to know if sun angle is computed as such θsin(sun_elev), where sun_elev is the sun elevation value specified in the landsat 8 metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calibrating Landsat-8 OLI to Top of Atmosphere:

```
R_toa_Bx = (M_Bx * DN_Bx + A_Bx) / sin (Sun_elev)
```

Where `R_toa_Bx` is reflectance in band_x, `M_Bx` is the multiplication factor stated in the metadata file, `DN_Bx` is the digital number in band_x from the TIFF-file, `A_Bx` is the addition number stated in the metadata file and `Sun_elev` is the sun elevation angle stated in the metadata file.

The most common mistake is problems with degrees and radians. As such, if your numbers are totally wrong, try changing `sin (Sun_elev)` to `sin (Sun_elev * Pi / 180)`.